# How do I create a script that assigns a value to a new column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, compare, rows

I have opportunities that are listed more than once and I need to create a column that ensures its only counted once. Here's a visual example of what I am trying to accomplish:

**Sample Data:**

[image]

And what I mean to do is assign the TCV Value in a new column the first time its encountered and 0 for every time after. So the opportunity is only counted once while still showing all the rows for influence.

**Expected Result:**

[image]

Comment: Why did Sarah get the TCV and not Mike or Rob?

Comment: In my case it doesn't matter who gets assigned the TCV as long as its only assigned once per opportunity. As long as Mike and Rob are still listed they get credit but the opportunity does not get counted twice when summed

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8.x you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function, as in:

```
select
  opportunity,
  influences,
  total_contract_value,
  case
    when row_number() over(partition by opportunity order by influences) = 1 
    then total_contract_value
    else 0
  end as tcv_counted_once
from my_table
```